# What's the best separator to separate data entities concatenated into a string?

Tags: mysql, string, string-concatenation

Assuming there are multiple data entities that need to be saved within a database (MySQL), for instance *font-size*, *font-weight*, *color* etc., some of which have fixed values and others are strings input by the user of the application, so they can hold any character whatsoever.
All this information needs to be concatenated and stored as a single, long string.

What is the best separator to use between these entities (assuming a small string), so as to avoid the situation in which that separator is found within the text input by the user?

BTW: I cannot create multiple columns for each individual entities.

Comment: The best separator is putting them into separate columns ;-)

Comment: That's out of the question, I'm afraid. I should have specified it from the beginning, sorry.

Comment: sounds like you're storing css? use a char or char sequence that's not legal in css

Comment: eav - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - i think is bad idea, you can't predict number of columns you will have

Comment: any that your client software will process without confusing with its own keywords

Comment: Why not create a separate table for them and use joins?

Comment: @ajreal If the number of columns is not known, separate table is a good solution. It is very very rare for a composite column to provide the best solution: inevitably, you run into problems down the road.

Comment: I'm not storing just CSS, there are also fields that can hold any character that the user inputs, as I've written above and I also cannot change the number of table fields, or db tables for that matter. I can only concatenate the entities into a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use some data structure language like json?

```
<?php 
// Array of strings
$strings = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3');

// Encode in json (return string)
$json = json_encode($strings);

// Add to your database
funcThatUpdateYourDatabase($json);
```

and after:

```
<?php
// Retrieve json from database;
$json = funcThatRetrieveYourColumn($json);

// convert back in array
$strings = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: Interesting idea. What PHP function would I then use to split the information into their individual entities?

Comment: Json in php is pretty simple. json_encode(array('string1', 'string2', 'string3')); and after to json_decode($json_string);
You can use assoc array too.
But if you plan to store class object search around serializer instead.

Answer (score 0):

As strange as your requirement sounds, just use a string of punctuation like /*^$%{] to seperate the values. It's very unlikely to occur by accident. Obviously the longer the string the safer it is to use as such.